# SSL/TLS Handshake failed - Unrecognized Name

Tags: ssl

I was trying for create a simple ssl server/client communication. I am running client now and monitor the Wireshark log. I am able to see the Client Hello message also verified the packet format ciphers and another parameters are correct in client side. but instead of server hello message I am getting
"Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unrecognized Name) "

I need the support for what is the root cause of the issue also I need support for how to fix the issue.

Comment: See [rfc6066 section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066#section-3). Either (1) the client is not sending the correct ServerNameIndication or (2) the server is not handling it correctly. You need to determine which is the case, but since you gave us no information about either the client or the server, we cannot help with whichever one is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am running client now and I was trying to communicate with the server traffic.libsyn.com and the server is alive also verify through ssllabs.com/ssltest 1. I was noticed previously there is no proper cipher suites i was added it. 2. I was verified with the Wireshark log in client_hello->Extension: instead of server_name i was noticed the renegotiation_info.

Comment: The server is 'alive' but as ssllabs tells you it 'works only in [clients] with SNI support'. If wireshark confirms your client isn't sending SNI, then either you need to fix your client or change the server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we refer the document TLS 1.2 RFC5246 they mention error code 112 means server name is not present in the packet, we added the server name. Now the issue was fixed.